# Goland IDE Typescript Support on .html files

Tags: typescript, go, goland

I'm coding in Go using the Goland IDE by Jetbrains.

How can I use typescript inside my .html template files? These files have HTML and CSS in them mixed with the JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion try using VS. Code for better support to all different languages and files. VS Code has a good support to Golang as well, been using that since last 5 years now.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and requires compilation before you can run your code in a browser.

You can compile your TypeScript code using GoLand by following the steps described in ["Compiling TypeScript into JavaScript"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/compiling-typescript-to-javascript.html).

You can then reference generated JS file in your HTML template via the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I voted you up since this is helpful, but I'm asking about .html files that are mixed with html and css. Thanks.